# How to install pysqlite?

Tags: python, linux, sqlite, gcc, pysqlite

I am trying to install pysqlite (Python interface to the SQLite). I downloaded the file with the package (pysqlite-2.5.5.tar.gz). And I did the following:

```
gunzip pysqlite-2.5.5.tar.gz
tar xvf pysqlite-2.5.5.tar
\cd pysqlite-2.5.5
python setup.py install
```

At the last step I have a problem. I get the following error message:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

[I found that other peoples also had this problem](http://forums.opensuse.org/applications/400363-gcc-fails-during-pysqlite-install.html).

As far as I understood in the person had a problem because sqlite2 was not installed. But in my case, I have sqlite3 (I can run it from command line).

May be I should change some paths in `"setup.cfg"`? At the moment I have there:

```
#define=
#include_dirs=/usr/local/include
#library_dirs=/usr/local/lib
libraries=sqlite3
define=SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION
```

And if I type "which sqlite3" I get:

```
/usr/bin/sqlite3
```

I saw a similar question here. The answer was "you need sqlite3-dev". But, even if it is the case, how to check if I have `sqlite3-dev`. And if I do not have it how to get it?

Can anybody pleas help me with that problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I type sys.version in Python session I get: '2.4.3 (#1, Jan 21 2009, 01:11:33) \n[GCC 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)]'. Does it mean that I have version 2.4.3 and I have no chance to use SQLite with this version?

Comment: I do not insist on compiling it myself. Actually, I do not know if I need to compile. I also do not know how to compile.

Comment: I do not know if my system use RPM package (I never used 'yum', probably because I never installed anything).

Comment: tinkertim, I did not get. You say that on system that use RPM packages and on most Debian based systems the package name is the same (sqlite3-devel)? Anyway, even if I know the package name, how should I use it? Should I install the package? If yes, how I do it? Moreover, I do not have administrator permissions on the computer. Will it be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to check if I have "sqlite3-dev"

That's entirely dependent on what Linux distro you're using -- is it Fedora, Suse, Ubuntu, Gentoo, Mandrake, or which other one out of the dozens out there; there are several packaging strategies and tools used to check which packages are there, get more, and so forth.

So, never ask questions about checking, getting or tweaking packages on Linux without specifying the distribution[s] of interest -- it makes it essentially impossible to offer precise, specific help.

**Edit**: the simplest way I know of getting details about your Linux distribution (works on all the ones I have at hand to try, but I don't have a particularly wide array...;-):

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_CODENAME=hardy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 8.04.2"
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=8.04
...etc, etc...
```

This is probably going to be the contents of file `/etc/lsb-release`, but I'm suggesting the `*-release` because I think there may be some other such files involved.

Of course, if the need to check your distro applies inside a file or program, reading this file (or files) and locating specific contents will also be quite feasible; but for the purpose of informing would-be helpers about what distro you're using, the `cat` at the shell prompt is going to be quite sufficient;-).

Comment: OK. Than how can I find out my Linux distro?

Comment: @Verrtex, edited my answer to provide advice on this new question of yours.

Comment: My system tells me: CentOS release 5.3 (Final).

Comment: For CentOS 5.3, try e.g. the instructions here: http://tuxmark.blogspot.com/2009/07/build-python-26-on-centos-53.html which should give you Python 2.6 (incorporating sqlite and much other goodness besides). (I have no CentOS 5.3 installation to verify those instructions, but, on the surface, they seem correct).

Answer (score 10):

For Debian distros I fixed this problem with

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Answer (score 6):

I was able to resolve the same build error by installing the sqlite-devel package:

```
sudo yum install sqlite-devel
```

Comment: is there something similar for windows ?

Comment: @AnkushRathi: There are Python and Sqlite packages for Chocolatey (Windows package manager), but I'm not sure if these will do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I'm using python 2.4, neither `sqlite3-dev` nor `libsqlite3-dev` are available for CentOS.

```
yum install python-devel
```

seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Python do you have? SQLite is integrated in Python since 2.5:

http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html

If you insist on compiling it yourself, the package is called sqlite3-devel, you can find it e.g. [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/7965440/com/sqlite3-devel-3.5.7-17.1.i586.rpm.html)

Comment: If I type sys.version in Python session I get: '2.4.3 (#1, Jan 21 2009, 01:11:33) \n[GCC 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)]'. Does it mean that I have version 2.4.3 and I have no chance to use SQLite with this version?

Comment: I do not insist on compiling it myself. Actually, I do not know if I need to compile. I also do not know how to compile.

Comment: @Verrtex, it IS possible to build sqlite for Python 2.4 (although installing and using a more recent version of Python also has other advantages -- don't overwrite the system-supplied version, that might break some things, but installing a newer one e.g. in /usr/local is perfectly fine).

Answer (score 2):

You could use yum or apt-get instead
first type :

```
    sudo yum(or apt-get) search python-sqlite3
```

you will get something like python-sqlite3dbm.noarch

then type :

```
    sudo yum(or apt-get) install python-sqlite3dbm.noarch
```

this way your os will install all you need for you and you wont get errors

Answer (score 1):

I had following compile errors on **CentOS release 5.6**:

```
src/cache.h:34: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'PyObject_HEAD'
src/cache.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'PyObject_HEAD'
src/cache.h:61: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'pysqlite_NodeType'
src/cache.h:62: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'pysqlite_CacheType'
src/cache.h:64: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyObject'
src/cache.h:64: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyObject'
src/cache.h:67: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyObject'
src/cache.h:67: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyObject'
```

Installing **python-devel** helped me too:

**yum install python-devel**

Answer (score 0):

I'm the one who answered the other question :) On systems that use RPM packages, i.e. you normally use 'yum' to install things, the package is named sqlite3-devel.

On most Debian based systems (i.e. you use apt-get to install packages), the package is named sqlite3-dev.

This is a very typical difference between the two, most other packages follow the same naming convention.

Comment: I do not know if my system use RPM package (I never used 'yum', probably because I never installed anything).

Comment: I did not get. You say that on system that use RPM packages and on most Debian based systems the package name is the same (sqlite3-devel)? Anyway, even if I know the package name, how should I use it? Should I install the package? If yes, how I do it? Moreover, I do not have administrator permissions on the computer. Will it be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble with gcc failing with Ubuntu Karmic. I fixed this by installing the python-dev package. In my case, I'm working with python2.4, so I installed the python2.4-dev package. The python-dev package should work for python2.6.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the python sqlite lib?

```
sudo apt-get install python-sqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the plug in http://yum.baseurl.org/download/yum-metadata-parser/

```
wget -c "http://yum.baseurl.org/download/yum-metadata-parser/yum-metadata-parser-1.1.4.tar.gz"
```

then install it

```
tar zxf yum-metadata-parser-1.1.4.tar.gz && cd yum-metadata-parser-1.1.4
/path/to/python setup.py install
```