# How to install sqlite3 for python 2.7 ( if not installed by default )

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I've installed python2.7 going through this tutorial: http://bicofino.io/2014/01/16/installing-python-2-dot-7-6-on-centos-6-dot-5/

everything's okay, but the python doesn't see sqlite module:

```
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

Is there a possibility to install it manually ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How did you install python2.7? Manually from python.org? If you installed it with a package manager it should be importable as `import sqlite3`

Comment: I downloaded and installed python from this page: http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.8/Python-2.7.8.tar.xz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this same issue when I was installing sqlite on a friends windows machine. You need to have the sqlite development files before installation. See link that people had this issue when installing on centos [How to install pysqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448819/how-to-install-pysqlite)

- `yum install sqlite-devel`
- `cd <python directory>`
- `./configure --prefix=<installdir>; make; make install`

Comment: I have already installed sqlite-devel and ran those commands. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126475/importerror-no-module-named-sqlite3-in-python3-3 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394013/problems-with-python-2-7-3-on-centos-with-sqlite3-module any help?

Comment: your answer is , I ran them once again and it worked